# Creating components with optional arguments/optional props

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create my first own components and wishes a simple solution how to create optional arguments, so I mean arguments which can be, but not needed to be used.

E.g. I can decide on usage wether I want to use

```
<my component :name="name" :description="description">
```

or only

```
<my component :name="name">
```

So in my view I just want to import the component "my component" regularly.
How should my component look like?

I've tried something like:

```
    <template>
     <input
        :id="name"
        :name="name"
        type="text"
        :description="description"
      />
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
       name: "adsInputText",
       props: {
         name: String,
         description: null
       },
    </script>
```

This is only a simplified abstraction of my problem. I have already played through several variants, but just couldn't get it right.

Do you know a simple approach to this?

Thanks a lot
Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to add an optional prop then you should indicate a type and might want to add a default value for it:

```
 props: {
         name: String,
         description: {
           type: String,
           default: null
         }
       },
```

That way if you don't indicate `description` prop when using a component you'll get `null` from `this.description` instead of `undefined`.